# Compile protobuf to python, cmake command

Tags: python, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have some proto definitions that I compile to cpp.
To generate the corresponding make target I use cmake like this:
`protobuf_generate_cpp(CPP_SOURCES PROTO_HEADERS ${PROTO_FILES})`
And I use the `CPP_SOURCES` to build my lib.

Now I need to compile the same proto files for python also and I added this:
`protobuf_generate_python(PY_SOURCES ${PROTO_FILES})`
This alone has no effect, and I am not sure what I should / can add more in order to have some make target that will trigger also the *protoc* for *python*

Comment: [`protobuf_generate_python`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L213) does exist in `FindProtobuf.cmake`, so perhaps you aren't using it correctly?

Comment: Yes it does exist, it's not that it gives and error, but it has no effect. I actually noticed it works after adding the resulting python sources to my cpp library target, which is weird. Maybe I can add a non binary target to pass the python sources to?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example for your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already answered your question, but here is a complete answer.

The protobuf_generate_python() function add's a [custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html). To trigger the command you need a define a target. So add a [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)() like this

```
add_custom_target(myTarget ALL 
                  DEPENDS ${PY_SOURCES})
```

Comment: Just for reference. I had to explicitly call `cd build && make myTarget` because I was not using it any where. To fix this, I added `${PY_SOURCE}` to my main target `DEPENDS`.